# My window.open open a new window instead of a new tab

Tags: javascript, window.open

When executing window.open I want to open a new tab but in my page it opens a new window.  How can I open in a new tab?

Here is my code :

```
                $('.visu_cr_pdf').click(function(){                 
                $.post("{ART_wwwroot}page.php?module={module}&action=gene_p4_pdf",$('#p4_cr'), function(data) {
                    var reponse = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if(reponse.status=='success'){


                        window.open('{ART_wwwroot}page.php?module={module}&action=visu_p4_cr','_blank');
                        return false;
                    }     
                });

            });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: You can't choose whether to open it in a new window or tab, it is just a browser setting.

Comment: You can't control how the browser deals with new windows.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the attribute *target="_blank"* directly in your form? ([the mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form))